# Flask web app on Heroku throwing Not Found

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first flask web app via Heroku. But when I go to my app, it always shows 'Not Found - The requested URL was not found on the server'.

I tried other routes such as /register, but they all show 'Not Found' page. It runs well on my cloud9 IDE, and deploys successfully on Heroku.

So what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

(I'm following this instruction: http://cdn.cs50.net/cscip14300/2017/seminars/from_harvard_to_heroku/from_harvard_to_heroku.pdf)

Here is my log:

```
2020-05-08T16:14:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user eungang3@naver.com
2020-05-08T16:14:31.901041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-05-08T16:14:31.914350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-05-08T16:14:30.785786+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0a1a17fe by user eungang3@naver.com
2020-05-08T16:14:30.785786+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user eungang3@naver.com
2020-05-08T16:14:37.844256+00:00 app[web.1]: * Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
2020-05-08T16:14:37.844285+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-05-08T16:14:37.844361+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2020-05-08T16:14:37.844446+00:00 app[web.1]: Use a production WSGI server instead.
2020-05-08T16:14:37.844479+00:00 app[web.1]: * Debug mode: on
2020-05-08T16:14:37.863075+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:50922/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-05-08T16:14:37.866366+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
2020-05-08T16:14:38.279279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-08T16:14:38.346889+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
2020-05-08T16:14:38.365832+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 618-739-473
2020-05-08T16:14:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-08T16:15:11.969153+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:werkzeug:10.186.239.155 - - [08/May/2020 16:15:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2020-05-08T16:15:11.969938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=women-who-read.herokuapp.com request_id=e48ab5b0-3b6b-45d1-84a2-9276d230b941 fwd="182.219.152.173" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
```

File structure:

```
~/
|-final/
 |--static/
  |---fallback.jpg
  |---script.js
  |---style.css
 |--templates/
  |---admin_index.html
  |---admin_search_result.html
  |---index.html
  |---layout.html
  |---login.html
  |---register.html
  |---search_result.html
  |---wishlist.html
 |--application.py
 |--final.db
 |--helpers.py
 |--Procfile
 |--requirements.txt
 |--runtime.txt
```

application.py(from beginning to index):

```
import psycopg2
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from helpers import login_required, lookup, wrongInput, getISBNList, saveInDB, deleteFromDB, getISBNInDB, getAuthorInDB, saveIn, getBookId, deleteFrom, getBookIdIn, getISBNIn

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT",8080))
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)

app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
db = SQL(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL") or "sqlite:///final.db")

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def index():
    authors = getAuthorInDB()

    if request.method == "GET":
        result = getISBNInDB()
        apiResult = []
        currentWish = getBookIdIn("wishlist")
        isItInWish = []

        for isbn in result:
            apiResult.append(lookup(isbn)[0])

            if getBookId(isbn) in currentWish:
                isItInWish.append(True)

            else:
                isItInWish.append(False)

    return render_template("index.html", result=apiResult, authors=authors, isItInWish=isItInWish)
```

Procfile:

```
web: python application.py
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.6
```

requirements.txt:

```
cs50
Flask
Flask-Session
passlib
SQLAlchemy
psycopg2
requests
```